# analytics, sitemap, routing all in one solution for Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, analytics, servicestack, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I'm planning all in one solution for analytics, sitemap and routing.

Which extension mechanism in Asp.Net mvc I have to use? Some of the sitemap and analytics problem could be resolved at routing level. I think there is overhead using 3rd party Sitemap solution. (https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider). More integrated solution will be better.

(For example I will store all  Url,Controller,Action info on Pagedb,  there will be regex maybe but also I will store them in db and cache)

Ps:I will use ServiceStack Mvc framework:) and asp.net mvc 4

Scenario:

- App_Start

  Prepare all urls via PageProvider (something like DynamicSiteMap feature in MvcSitemapProvider)

  All URLs are stored and cached with Controller,Action, Parameters as object (Also Sitemap is ready)
- App_BeginRequest

  Check URL is PageCache

  - if exists *update analytics* and run via strong typed parameters
  - if not exists check valid and add to PageCache go former option